# Group of mappings containing an injective map is a subset of symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of mappings on a set $X$ with respect to function composition. Show that if $G$ contains some injective function, then $G\subseteq \text{Sym}(X)$.

What I did: If $X$ is finite, then the injective mapping $g\in G$ is also bijective. Suppose the identity $i\in G$ is not bijective. Then $gi=g$ is not bijective, impossible, so $i$ must be bijective. Then any $h\in G$ must be bijective because of the existence of $h^{-1}$ such that $hh^{-1}=i$. So $G\subseteq\text{Sym}(X)$ indeed.

But when $X$ is infinite, the injective mapping is no longer necessarily bijective, and the whole argument breaks down.

Comment: If $G$ is a group comprised of mappings then those mappings must be invertible (since every element of a group must have an inverse) hence $G$ is a subset of the collection of invertible mappings, in symbols that is $G\subseteq{\rm Sym}(X)$. The fact that all of $G$'s elements are bijective functions is automatically true, there is no "if" about it, which makes the phrasing here seem strange.

Comment: @anon Those mappings might not be invertible, since the "identity" of $G$ is not necessarily the "identity mapping". For example, take $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $G$ be the group of mappings from $(x,y)$ to $(0,\lambda y)$ for all $\lambda\neq 0$. Here the "identity" of $G$ is the mapping $(x,y)$ to $(0,y)$, i.e. when $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks - I did not realize there could be subgroups in the monoid of functions on a set that did not contain the identity mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recipe for how you can do it:

1. Prove that $i$ is injective
2. Prove every $h\in G$ is injective
3. Prove that $i$ is surjective (consider $i=i^2$)
4. Prove every $h\in G$ is surjective

At each stage, employ proof by contradiction. Spoiler:

> Suppose $g\in G$ is injective. Suppose that $i$ is not injective. Then $gi=g$ is not injective, absurd, so $i$ is injective. Suppose $h\in G$ is not injective. Then $h^{-1}h=i$ is not injective, absurd, so every element of $G$ is an injective function. Suppose $i\in G$ is not surjective. Then $\exists x\in X$ such that $x\not\in i(X)$. But then $i(x)\in i(X)$, but $i(x)=i^2(y)\implies x=i(y)$ hence $i(x)\not\in i^2(X)$, hence $i\ne i^2$, a contradiction. Hence $i$ is surjective. Suppose now that $h\in G$ is not surjective. Then $h h^{-1}=i$ is not surjective, a contradiction. Hence every element is surjective as well as injective.

Comment: For the first step: Suppose $X=\mathbb{Z}$, $g(x) = 2x$, $i(x)=x$ if $x$ even, $i(x)=x+1$ if $x$ odd. Then $gi=g$ is injective, but $i$ is not injective.

Comment: @PaulS With your functions, $i(1)=2=i(2)$ so $g(i(1))=g(i(2))$. Can you extrapolate from this example to see that $i$ not injective implies $gi$ not injective?

Comment: Ah, my notation for $gi$ vs $ig$ is reversed from yours. I get this step now.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ contains an injective map then it suffices to show that the identity of $G$ must be the identity of the monoid $X^X$, i.e. the identity map.

Let $e$ be the identity of $G$ and $f$ an injective function in $G$, then $f(e(x)) = e(x)$ for all $x \in X$. 
Hence, $e$ is also injective. 
This is sufficient to show that $e(x) = x$ for all $x \in G$ since $e(e(x)) = e(x)$.